# Lost screen on Panasonic 55 inch with Mac mini

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini

I tried to set the screen from the Panasonic to best fit.
When I did that on my Mac mini the screen went to snow.
I tried to get it back by on losing the HDMI cable power of the Mac. Nothing helps. When I start up the Mac the screen is going to snow. It works well on 720p and 1080i but can't go back there.

Comment: in about this mac, look how the Panasonic is identified as? Also in ColorSync utility (utility folder) look what profiles is been used for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [resetting your NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) (formerly PRAM).

**Resetting NVRAM**

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P,
   and R.
3. Turn on your Mac.
4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you
   hear the startup sound. Hold these keys until the computer restarts
   and you hear the startup sound for a second time.
5. Release the keys.

After resetting NVRAM, you may need to reconfigure settings for speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, and time zone information.